# Probability of getting 2 aces in a hand of two cards

Tags: probability

Choose 2 cards randomly from a deck of 52 playing cards. Let $E_1$ be the even that you picked 2 aces and $E_2$ be the event that you picked two cards with same value. Find $P(E_i)$ $i=1,2$.

ATTTEMPT:

The sample space is the set of all two-card hands. So its size is ${52 \choose 2}$. Now, lets find $|E_1|$. We only have 4 aces and we want two of them so that gives ${4 \choose 2}$ hence

$$ P(E_1) = \frac{ {4 \choose 2 }}{ {52 \choose 2 }} $$

As for the second one, notice we can let $A_k$ be the event that the two cards have kth denominations where $k$ ranges from ace to king. We can write $E_1 = \bigcup_{k=1}^{13} A_k $. Hence,

$$ P(E_1) = \sum P(A_k) $$

To find $P(A_k)$ notice first pick 2 suits we count this in ${4 \choose 2}$ ways and then kth denomination and since there are 13 of then we have

$$ P(A_k) = \frac{13 {4 \choose 2} }{ {52 \choose 2} } $$

Tehrefore,

$$ P(E_1) = \sum  \frac{13 {4 \choose 2} }{ {52 \choose 2} } = \boxed{  \frac{13^2 {4 \choose 2} }{ {52 \choose 2} } } $$

Am I correct?

Comment: I presume $A_1$ is the event that both cards are aces. That means $A_1=E_1$. So then $P(A_1)=P(E_1)$.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, for the first.

$$\mathsf P(E_1)= \frac{\dbinom 4 2}{\dbinom{52}2}$$

No, for the next.   You are not seeking a selection of any one from thirteen ranks, rather you are specifically seeking rank $k$.   As a reality check you should have: $\mathsf P(A_1)=\mathsf P(E_1)$.

The probability for obtaining $2$ from the $4$ cards of rank $k$, when selecting $2$ from the $52$ cards, is: $$\mathsf P(A_k)= \frac{\dbinom 4 2}{\dbinom{52}2}$$

---

The probability for obtaining $2$ from $4$ cards of the same rank for any $1$ from $13$ ranks when so selecting, is then$$\mathsf P(E_2)=\sum\limits_{k=1}^{13}\mathsf P(A_k) = \dfrac{\dbinom{13}1\dbinom 42}{\dbinom{52}2}$$